# spark.databricks.queryWatchdog.outputRatioThreshold Error for FPGrowth using Pyspark on Databricks

Tags: pyspark, bigdata, databricks, market-basket-analysis, fpgrowth

I'm working on Market Basket Analysis using Pyspark on Databricks.
The transactional dataset consists of a total of 5.4 Million transactions, with approx. 11,000 items.
I'm able to run FPGrowth on the dataset, but whenever I'm trying to either display or take a count of model.freqItemsets & model.associationRules, I'm getting this weird error every time:

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 88 cancelled because Task 8084 in Stage 283 exceeded the maximum allowed ratio of input to output records (1 to 235158, max allowed 1 to 10000); this limit can be modified with configuration parameter spark.databricks.queryWatchdog.outputRatioThreshold

I'm not even able to understand why am I facing this error, and how I can resolve the same.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I tried reading the docs provided by Databricks, yet I'm not clearly able to understand why am I getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I assume your are using an interactive cluster/workflow or share the same cluster with multiple users. You can enable Query Watchdog by either in notebook (will be reflected only during the runtime) or at cluster config.

Enable Watchdog with `spark.databricks.queryWatchdog.enabled`.
Configure the task runtime with `spark.databricks.queryWatchdog.minTimeSecs`.
Display output with `spark.databricks.queryWatchdog.minOutputRows`.
Configure the output ratio with `spark.databricks.queryWatchdog.outputRatioThreshold`.

The default value for the *outputRatioThreshold* is 1000 but you can increase and find optimum value based on your analysis.
e.g (scala code, but can be python or sql or even in cluster config as well)

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.queryWatchdog.enabled", true)
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.queryWatchdog.outputRatioThreshold", 1000L)
```

For more details refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/query-watchdog (Azure DBX)

I am using Azure DBX but the same is applicable for DBX in AWS as well or even in GCP